# Pandas : Make new dataframe from selected column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sorry if this question has been asked, I don't know the keyword for it.

Let say I have a dataframe with 500 features, I call it df_raw. After features selection process, I manage to get top 50 features. I want to use those top 50 features to select column on df_raw, and make a new dataframe out of it, how can I achieve this?

I want something like this basically:

```
df_raw:

A   B   C   D   E   F   J   K   L   M
=====================================
0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
```

Top 3 Features : C, J, L

```
new_df:

C   J   L
=========
0   0   0
0   0   1
1   1   0
```

only on a larger scale

Edit 2 : Added my real dataframe

```
ad  addict  ade     adik    ah  aja     ajar    ak  akses   aktif   ...     warga   wkwk    wkwkw   wkwkwk  x   ya  yaa     yg  yuk     Sentimen
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   2   0   1   0   2   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
11  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
12  0   0   0   0   0   3   1   0   1   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   1   0   2   0   1
13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
14  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
17  0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
18  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
19  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
20  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
21  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   ...     1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   2
22  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
23  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   2
24  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ...     0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
25  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
26  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
27  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
28  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   2
29  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2

30 rows × 340 columns
```

Top 108 features :

```
ade             0.000000
ah              0.000000
aja             0.030054
ajar            0.070682
ak              0.000000
alias           0.000000
ama             0.000000
anak            0.038516
auk             0.000000
banget          0.020754
bayarin         0.000000
beban           0.000000
biar            0.033700
bikin           0.000000
darurat         0.000000
dikerjainnya    0.000000
do              0.000000
dom             0.000000
emaknya         0.000000
ga              0.018862
gerak           0.000000
gerombol        0.000000
gimana          0.000000
gin             0.060764
gurune          0.000000
hemat           0.000000
i               0.000000
isi             0.000000
jakarta         0.000000
jarang          0.000000
                  ...   
rindu           0.000000
ringan          0.000000
rutin           0.000000
saking          0.000000
sampe           0.000000
sekolah         0.193896
sempat          0.000000
sempet          0.000000
sesuai          0.000000
smpe            0.000000
sni             0.000000
sragam          0.000000
stress          0.000000
t               0.000000
takut           0.000000
tambah          0.000000
taun            0.000000
tdk             0.000000
teknologi       0.000000
temennya        0.000000
test            0.000000
things          0.000000
to              0.000000
tp              0.021611
tukeran         0.000000
udah            0.000000
udh             0.000000
umur            0.000000
wajar           0.000000
yg              0.000000
Length: 108, dtype: float64
```

I want to be able to select column on my dataframe based on the Top 108 features, and make a new dataframe out of it

Comment: I am not so clear on what the question is. If you only want to select tree columns try: df_raw[["C", "J", "L"]]

Comment: I could select it manually if my dataframe is small, but my dataframe is kinda big, so I want to automate the process. Maybe I add my real dataframe on the question

Comment: How are you determining the "top 3 features"?

Comment: mutual_info_classif, basically I already have a list on what is the 'top features'. what I want is the means to select column on my dataframe based on the 'top features' and make a new dataframe from it. And these top features, has the same name as some of my dataframe column since I use the dataframe to count the feature values

Comment: Can't you just use the index of that series to select the columns from the dataframe  `df[mutual_info_classif.index]`?

Comment: thank you @HenryEcker, you just solve it with one line!

Answer (score 0):

Let's just say you have a dataframe named df.

If you want to choose one column, just pass the name of that column into the brackets like df[name_of_the_column].

If you want to choose more than one column, pass the list of names in the same manner: df[[list_of_columns]].

You mentioned automation but this is not a complex act. So, i am not sure how automation can help. I think any form of automation makes it even longer and complex.

Comment: Ok, I got the Idea, but how can I get the name of column from 'Top 108 features' then? I save it in a dictionary.

Comment: Are these features saved somewhere? for example in a text file or something? You can read those names and save them into a Python list. Then pass that list to df[].

Comment: yes, I save it in a gain_ratio_dict. And the name list is classified as Index, so when I do this df[[gain_ratio_dict.keys()]], it returns KeyError: "None of [Index([('....')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: You are passing a dictionary keys object to the dataframe not a list! Try this: df[list(gain_ratio_dict_keys())]

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but the person above just solve it for me.